# Why isn't the right layout displayed?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to learn layouts.
The layout I am trying to do is:

```
 ___________________________________________________
|                                                   |
|                    VIEW PAGER                     |
|___________________________________________________|
|                         |                         |
|           TEXT          |           TEXT          |
|_________________________|_________________________|
|            |            |            |            |
|            |    TEXT    |            |    TEXT    |
|    TEXT    |____________|    TEXT    |____________|
|            |            |            |            |
|            |    TEXT    |            |    TEXT    |
|____________|____________|____________|____________|
```

Can someone please help me understand why the right part of the layout (the one after the comment NEXT INFO CELL) under the viewpage is not displayed and how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/friend_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/friend_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Previous Info"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
             >
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Bla"
                    />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Bla Bla"
                        android:gravity="center"
                    />
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Bla Bla Bla"
                        android:gravity="center"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

<!-- NEXT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next Info"
            />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            >
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Bla"
                />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Bla Bla"
                        android:gravity="center"
                    />
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Bla Bla Bla"
                        android:gravity="center"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And this is the simplest example exhibiting the problem? If you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) you might answer your own question. And if not it will get rid of the clutter that is irrelevant.

Comment: @weston:well I don't know what part is irrelevant.I did notice that if I change the `layout_width` of the left cell to be `wrap_content` then both layouts are displayed but I want them to take equal space

Comment: "well I don't know what part is irrelevant" find out! Did you read the link?

Comment: @weston:I updated OP to show what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simplified version of your problem. It has nothing to do with the outer `RelativeLayout` or the `TextView`s. This is what I meant by an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for this problem. I've trimmed the fat but still see the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffff0000" />

    <!-- NEXT -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You are using weights incorrectly, this example works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff0000" />

    <!-- NEXT -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

Comment: That is strange. In the tutorials I have read I don't ever remember setting a value for weight_sum. It is actually the first time I see this attribute

Comment: Technically it is not required if you are setting weights on each of the children. This example will work without it. However if you want to omit the `layoutWeight` from one, or don't even have a second view and need the gap, then you need the sum. It sounds like the tutorials you have been doing are less than complete in covering this area.

Answer (score 1):

You say that they need to take equal space.
Try using 
layout_weight = "0.5" 
layout_width = "0dp" 
 for same level child-layouts that need to have the same horizontal width.

Add to the children

Comment: Add these to parent or the children?